# how passing web url string to function

Tags: iphone, webview, mkannotation

I have a problem passing a string to a function that is an web address in order  to open that particular direction through a webview.

```
-(IBAction)toWeb:(NSString*)web_direction {
    UIViewController *webViewController = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    UIWebView *uiWebView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)] autorelease];

     [uiWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:web_direction]]];

    [webViewController.view addSubview: uiWebView];
    webViewController.title = @"web bar";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];

}
```

I want to call that function via   MKannotation using:

```
NSString *direction = @"http://www.google.com";
[btnDetails addTarget:self action:@selector(toWeb:direction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

But the app crashes. Any idea about that?

Comment: usually the sender is sent when you call an IBAction, I am not sure what you are trying to do using that string there.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass parameters in that manner with @selector().  @selector() is only meant to reference a selector to invoke in response to something, in this case a target on a button.

If you want to invoke different urls based on the button pressed, here's a suggestion on how to approach it (for this sample I use three different buttons to show you how you can conditionally use different urls based on the button pressed):

This goes where you are setting the targets:

```
btnDetailsForGoogle.tag = 1;
[btnDetailsForGoogle addTarget:self action:@selector(toWeb:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btnDetailsForYahoo.tag = 2;
[btnDetailsForYahoo addTarget:self action:@selector(toWeb:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btnDetailsForBing.tag = 3;
[btnDetailsForBing addTarget:self action:@selector(toWeb:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And here's the updated IBAction method

```
-(IBAction)toWeb:(id)sender {
    NSString *web_direction = @"";
    if (((UIButton *)sender).tag == 1)  web_direction = @"www.google.com";
    if (((UIButton *)sender).tag == 2)  web_direction = @"www.yahoo.com";
    if (((UIButton *)sender).tag == 3)  web_direction = @"www.bing.com";
    UIViewController *webViewController = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    UIWebView *uiWebView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)] autorelease];

     [uiWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:web_direction]]];

    [webViewController.view addSubview: uiWebView];
    webViewController.title = @"web bar";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: That is a good way but in my case, I read some info like name, position, and weburl from a json string. I put the position on map and i read the name touching the annotation pin. the idea was open the webpage passing the web url string. Perarps, as you say, I can call in the a a fuctin that read this string and return it there? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

A selector is the name of the method; it doesn't include parameters.  You would need to use...

```
[btnDetails addTarget:self action:@selector(toWeb:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

...and find another way to get the URL string.  The parameter that `toWeb:` gets is the button (usually called "sender").